# How to search in same-type columns given a set of unsorted values?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a system which backlogs products users receive within a box. The whole system is based on these kits we create with products inside.

So I got a `Customers` and `Products` which lists everything I have. And I have a `Boxes` table which has `ProductID1, ProductID2, ProductID3 and ProductID4` fields and `CustomerID` field to point which customer received which box.

All I want to do is, given a set of products **not in the same order** (Ex.: `ID4, ID2, ID3, ID1`) I need to know all customers that hadn't received any products of this given set.

Is my database bad designed? What would be the best way to do this or how to make the `SELECT` query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want as:

```
where id4 not in (productid1, productid2, productid3, productid4) or
      id2 not in (productid1, productid2, productid3, productid4) or
      id3 not in (productid1, productid2, productid3, productid4) or
      id1 not in (productid1, productid2, productid3, productid4)
```

You should have a table called something like `BoxesrProducts` that would have a `BoxesId` and a `ProductId`.  That way, boxes can have different sizes -- even beyond 4 products -- if that is desirable.

Comment: How should my table have been designed?